# What is the full name for LZVN, the compression algorithm?

Tags: compression

The LZVN algorithm, like the better-known [LZFSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZFSE), is introduced in macOS 10.9 for decmpfs. It was [discovered in 2014 as a kernelcache compressor](https://pikeralpha.wordpress.com/2014/06/04/os-x-10-10-yosemite-dp1-kernelcache/) before the official [WWDC 2016 release of LZFSE](https://github.com/lzfse/lzfse), which also contains an LZVN implementation for smaller streams.

But what does LZVN stand for? Apple documentation does not like talking about LZVN at all, and there does not seem to be anything online that mentions it. From reading the code I can see it is a LZSS algorithm with three lengths of L,M,D (REP) encodings, but this does not get me much closer to the actual name. Is there anything from Apple that I have missed?